# Bluetooth headset and HD voice

Tags: bluetooth-audio, headset

I'm trying to achieve better quality for remote communications. Thus, I'm trying to use a high quality headset for Skype calls.

The problem is, when connecting a headset to Android phone (both of them have HD voice support), the sound quality is very limited, i.e. much worse than Skype gives via the same phone's speaker & microphone.

Supporting cases:

- When I listen to music from phone using headset via bluetooth, the quality is good.
- When I use USB dongle (which is provided for headset with UC support, and appearing as audio device in system) for Skype with my laptop, the quality is good.

In all cases, I was using WiFi (NOT mobile data).
I was using Skype call testing service for all tests.

Is there some way to force codec or bluetooth profile to enable HD voice with Android for headset?

---

Phone: Galaxy Note 3 (has HD voice support).

Phone OS: Android 5.0.

Skype version on the phone: v6.13.0.608

Headset: Jabra Motion UC (has HD voice support).

Laptop: HP EliteBook 8460p

Laptop's OS: Ubuntu Linux 14.04.03

Skype version on laptop: 4.3.0.37

Comment: @beeshyams does it able to mask the headset, so apps will think that there's no headset attached?
I've found that it's Skype app who giving bad quality, specifically for bluetooth.

Comment: The app description claims that it does but I am unable to verify. You may like to check, though you have localized the problem to Skype. In the absence of verifying myself, would not like to post it as answer to a bounty question

Comment: App says *Wired Headset detection - ALLOW or IGNORE the headphone/headset plug in/out detection. 
Wired Headset microphone - DETECT or IGNORE that a headset has a microphone when plugged in*

Comment: Could you add some more detail about the hardware and the configurations in your examples? For example replacing "When I listen to music from headset" with "When I connect the headset to (device) using (connection method) and use (app) to play music". What OS is running on your laptop? What version of Skype is running on your laptop, and what version on your phone? Is there any difference depending on whether you are on mobile data vs. Wi-Fi? How does the sound quality for ordinary phone calls compare to Skype (for both headset and built-in)? How about your mic's quality for the other person?

Comment: @DanHenderson, I updated the question. Not checked mobile data vs WiFi though - everything was using WiFi. As for ordinary phone calls, that's an interesting question too, but there's a carrier factor involved, so it's more complex. For me it looks like bluetooth profile -related issue.

Comment: Also, my flatmate's girlfriend calls me frequently via Skype. Sometimes I answer from phone, sometimes from laptop. And her voice sounds much better when I answer from laptop :)))

Answer (score 2):

I've found that it's an issue of Skype application.
E.g. Google Hangouts gives good sound quality with and without bluetooth headset both.

I've filed a bug report here: https://community.skype.com/t5/Android/Forced-low-quality-voice-with-bluetooth-headsets/td-p/4366926